# Atributo data-image-src de libreria parallax.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola buenas tardes estoy usando la libreria parallax.js para mis efectos en las imagenes de fondo de mi pagina web. tengo un problema a la hora de querer cambiar una imagen con un evento de jquery utilizando attr...

```
<div id="imageChange" class="backgrounds parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/background1.png"></div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container2").mouseover(function(){
        $("#imageChange").attr('data-image-src', 'img/background2.png');

    });
});
```

A la hora de inspeccionar elemento si cambia por background2 pero en la pagina no se actualiza la imagen.